# Delphi XE7, trouble compiling, Undeclared identifier: 'TIdPeerThread'

Tags: delphi, compilation, delphi-xe7, indy10, indy-9

I am not a Delphi programmer and I need to do some changes in a program and re-compile. But, the problem is that I can not re-compile the source I already have. I have traced the problem, and it seems to be because of Delphi XE7 using Indy 10 instead of Indy 9. And since TIdPeerThread does not exist in Indy 10 I get errors.

I'll really appreciate it if you help me on how to modify the code so it is compatible with Indy 10 and I can recompile it in Delphi XE7.

```
library TCPServer;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Forms,
  IdTCPServer,
  IdTCPClient,
  Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

const
  nInputs = 60;
  nOutputs = 60;
type
  ts = array[0..255] of char;
  array_in = array[1..nInputs] of single;
  array_out = array[1..nOutputs] of single;
  Thelper = class
    IdTCPServer: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
    procedure IdTCPServer1DisConnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
  end;

var
  helper: Thelper;

  server_to_be_send: string = '';
  server_lastread: string = '';

  firsttimecall : boolean = true;

  inputvector_delay : array_in;
  outputvector_delay : array_out;
  time_old : single = -1.0;

procedure Thelper.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
  try
    Write('Connect from '+AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.IP+':'+IntToStr(AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port));
    WriteLn(' (peer '+AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP+':'+IntToStr(AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort)+')');
  except
  end;
end;

procedure Thelper.IdTCPServer1DisConnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
  try
    Write('Disconnect to '+AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.IP+':'+IntToStr(AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port));
    WriteLn(' (peer '+AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP+':'+IntToStr(AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort)+')');
  except
  end;
end;

procedure Thelper.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  ii : Integer;
begin
  IdTCPServer.OnExecute := nil;
  while true do
  begin
    Application.ProcessMessages();
    if (server_to_be_send<>'') then
    begin
      AThread.Connection.WriteLn(server_to_be_send);
      server_to_be_send := '';
      server_lastread := AThread.Connection.ReadLn('*',5000);
      if server_lastread='' then
        for ii:=1 to nInputs do server_lastread := server_lastread + '0;';
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure tcplink(na:integer;var inputvector : array_in;
                  nb:integer;var outputvector: array_out);stdcall;
var
  i : Integer;
  st : string;
begin

  // Ensure English locale decimal separator symbol
  DecimalSeparator := '.';

  if firsttimecall then
  begin
    firsttimecall := false;

    helper := Thelper.Create();
    helper.IdTCPServer := TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnExecute := helper.IdTCPServer1Execute;
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnConnect := helper.IdTCPServer1Connect;
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnDisconnect := helper.IdTCPServer1DisConnect;
    helper.IdTCPServer.DefaultPort := 1239;
    try
      helper.IdTCPServer.Active := true;
      if helper.IdTCPServer.Active then
        Writeln('TCP/IP host ready, default port: '+IntToStr(helper.IdTCPServer.DefaultPort));
    except
      Writeln('*** Could not start TCP/IP server ***');
    end;
  end;

  st := IntToStr(nInputs)+';'; for i:=1 to nInputs do st := st + FloatToStr(inputvector[i])+';';
  server_lastread := '';
  server_to_be_send := st;

  while (server_lastread='') do Application.ProcessMessages();

  st := server_lastread;
  server_lastread := '';

  for i:=1 to nOutputs do
  begin
    if Length(st) < 1 then
    begin
      outputvector[i] := 0;
    end
    else
    begin
      outputvector[i] := StrToFloat(copy(st,1,AnsiPos(';',st)-1));
      st := copy(st,AnsiPos(';',st)+1,MaxInt);
    end;
  end;
end;

// Only call tcplink when time has changed
Procedure tcplink_delay(na:integer;var inputvector : array_in;
                  nb:integer;var outputvector: array_out);stdcall;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  if inputvector[1] > time_old then
  begin
    tcplink(na, inputvector_delay, nb, outputvector_delay);
    time_old := inputvector[1];
  end;

  for i :=1 to nInputs do inputvector_delay[i] := inputvector[i];
  for i :=1 to nOutputs do outputvector[i] := outputvector_delay[i];

end;

Procedure tcplink_init(var string256:ts; length:integer);stdcall;
var
  init_str : string[255];
  onPos : Integer;
begin
  init_str:=strpas(string256);
  // Crop trailing blanks
  onPos := AnsiPos(' ', init_str);
  SetLength(init_str, onPos-1);

  if firsttimecall then
  begin
    firsttimecall := false;

    helper := Thelper.Create();
    helper.IdTCPServer := TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnExecute := helper.IdTCPServer1Execute;
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnConnect := helper.IdTCPServer1Connect;
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnDisconnect := helper.IdTCPServer1DisConnect;
    helper.IdTCPServer.DefaultPort := StrToInt(init_str);

    try
      helper.IdTCPServer.Active := true;
      if helper.IdTCPServer.Active then

        Writeln('TCP/IP host ready, selected port: '+IntToStr(helper.IdTCPServer.DefaultPort));
    except
      Writeln('*** Could not start TCP/IP server ***');
    end;
  end;

end;

Procedure tcplink_delay_init(var string256:ts; length:integer);stdcall;

begin
  tcplink_init(string256, length);
end;

exports
  tcplink, tcplink_delay, tcplink_init, tcplink_delay_init;

begin
end.
```

Comment: If you know that is the reason [this will probably give you the solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=+Indy+10+9+TIdPeerThread)

Comment: Well, thanks for the quick reply! I had tried it already :)
I actually switched from `TIdPeerThread` to `TIdContext` and used `AContext` instead of `AThread` in the code. I also had to change `AThread.Connection.WriteLn` to `AContext.Connection.iohandler.WriteLn`.

Now the code compiles, but does not work! Any help here is appreciated very much!

Comment: Please describe 'does not work'. What errors? What do you see in the debugger for values returning? You may not be a Delphi programmer but you're going to have to learn the IDE because we can't debug for you ;-) It may also help if you [edit] your question and put in your modified Indy10 parts next to the Indy9 ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the original code was written for Indy 9, so it needs to be updated to Indy 10.

It also appears to have been written for a pre-Unicode version of Delphi. `ts` is an array of `Char`, which is `AnsiChar` in Delphi 2007 and earlier, and `WideChar` in Delphi 2009 and later.  And Indy 9 does not support Unicode versions of Delphi.  So I would assume that `Char` in this case is intended to be `AnsiChar`.

There are also some small logic issues being made as well.

Here is an Indy 10 version, with some additional fixes/tweaks:

```
library TCPServer;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Forms,
  IdContext,
  IdTCPServer,
  Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

const
  nInputs = 60;
  nOutputs = 60;

type
  ts = array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
  array_in = array[1..nInputs] of Single;
  array_out = array[1..nOutputs] of Single;

  Thelper = class
    IdTCPServer: TIdTCPServer;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1DisConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
  end;

var
  helper: Thelper = nil;

  server_to_be_send: string = '';
  server_lastread: string = '';

  inputvector_delay : array_in;
  outputvector_delay : array_out;
  time_old : single = -1.0;

destructor Thelper.Destroy;
begin
  IdTCPServer.Active := false;
  IdTCPServer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure Thelper.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := Format('Connect on %s:%d (peer %s:%d)', [AContext.Binding.IP, AContext.Binding.Port, AContext.Binding.PeerIP, AContext.Binding.PeerPort]);
  WriteLn(s);
end;

procedure Thelper.IdTCPServer1DisConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := Format('Disconnect from %s:%d (peer %s:%d)', [AContext.Binding.IP, AContext.Binding.Port, AContext.Binding.PeerIP, AContext.Binding.PeerPort]);
  WriteLn(s);
end;

procedure Thelper.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ii : Integer;
  s : string;
begin
  if (server_to_be_send <> '') then
  begin
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(server_to_be_send);
    finally
      server_to_be_send := '';
    end;
    s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn('*', 5000);
    if s = '' then
    begin
      for ii := 1 to nInputs do
        s := s + '0;';
    end;
    server_lastread := s;
  end else begin
    Sleep(10);
  end;
end;

procedure tcplink(na: Integer; var inputvector: array_in;
                  nb: Integer; var outputvector: array_out); stdcall;
var
  i : Integer;
  st : string;
  t: Cardinal;
begin
  if helper = nil then
  begin
    helper := Thelper.Create;
    helper.IdTCPServer := TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnExecute := helper.IdTCPServer1Execute;
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnConnect := helper.IdTCPServer1Connect;
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnDisconnect := helper.IdTCPServer1DisConnect;
    helper.IdTCPServer.DefaultPort := 1239;
    helper.IdTCPServer.MaxConnections := 1;
  end;
  if not helper.IdTCPServer.Active then
  try
    helper.IdTCPServer.Active := true;
    Writeln('TCP/IP host ready, default port: '+IntToStr(helper.IdTCPServer.DefaultPort));
  except
    Writeln('*** Could not start TCP/IP server ***');
    Exit;
  end;

  st := IntToStr(nInputs)+';';
  for i:=1 to nInputs do st := st + FloatToStr(inputvector[i])+';';
  server_lastread := '';
  server_to_be_send := st;

  t := Ticks;
  while (server_lastread = '') and (GetTickDiff(t, Ticks) < 10000) do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

  st := server_lastread;
  server_lastread := '';

  for I := 1 to nOutputs do
  begin
    if Length(st) < 1 then begin
      outputvector[i] := 0;
    end else
    begin
      outputvector[i] := StrToFloat(Copy(st,1,Pos(';',st)-1));
      st := Copy(st,Pos(';',st)+1,MaxInt);
    end;
  end;
end;

// Only call tcplink when time has changed
procedure tcplink_delay(na: Integer; var inputvector : array_in;
                        nb: Integer; var outputvector: array_out); stdcall;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  if inputvector[1] > time_old then
  begin
    tcplink(na, inputvector_delay, nb, outputvector_delay);
    time_old := inputvector[1];
  end;

  for i :=1 to nInputs do inputvector_delay[i] := inputvector[i];
  for i :=1 to nOutputs do outputvector[i] := outputvector_delay[i];
end;

procedure tcplink_init(var string256: ts; length: Integer); stdcall;
var
  init_str : string;
  onPos : Integer;
begin
  init_str := strpas(string256);
  // Crop trailing blanks
  onPos := Pos(' ', init_str);
  SetLength(init_str, onPos-1);

  if helper = nil then
  begin
    helper := Thelper.Create;
    helper.IdTCPServer := TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnExecute := helper.IdTCPServer1Execute;
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnConnect := helper.IdTCPServer1Connect;
    helper.IdTCPServer.OnDisconnect := helper.IdTCPServer1DisConnect;  
    helper.IdTCPServer.MaxConnections := 1;
  end;
  if not helper.IdTCPServer.Active then
  try
    helper.IdTCPServer.DefaultPort := StrToInt(init_str);
    helper.IdTCPServer.Active := true;
    Writeln('TCP/IP host ready, selected port: '+IntToStr(helper.IdTCPServer.DefaultPort));
  except
    Writeln('*** Could not start TCP/IP server ***');
    Exit;
  end;
end;

procedure tcplink_delay_init(var string256: ts; length: Integer); stdcall;
begin
  tcplink_init(string256, length);
end;

procedure tcplink_cleanup; stdcall;
begin
  FreeAndNil(helper);
end;

exports
  tcplink, tcplink_delay, tcplink_init, tcplink_delay_init, tcplink_cleanup;

begin
  // Ensure English locale decimal separator symbol
  FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator := '.';
end.
```

That being said, since the original code appears to be designed for a single TCP connection at a time, and `tcplink()` sends a command and waits for a reply, this code could probably be re-written to use `TIdSimpleServer` instead of `TIdTCPServer`.  Unlike `TIdTCPServer`, `TIdSimpleServer` is not a multi-threaded component, so it would allow `tcplink()` to be more self-contained and linear: wait for a connection, send a command, read a reply, done.  No need for global string variables, event handlers, busy waits, etc.